# MYSql after update trigger not updating table

Tags: mysql

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER 
TRIGGER `radia`.`orderstable_AFTER_UPDATE` 
  UPDATE ON `orderstable`
  FOR EACH ROW begin 
      SET @VATCharged = Amount * (VAT*0.01);
```

But the VATCharged column does not update after there is a change to the amount or VAT.

The table has the following columns; Order Number(INT), AccNo(VARCHAR), Invoice Number(VARCHAR), Description(VARCHAR), Amount(INT), VAT(INT) and VATCharged(INT).

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `old` or `new` against the column to get either old value before update or new value after update

```
set  @VATCharged := new.Amount * (new.VAT*0.01);
```

EDIT :
If you want to update the `VATCharged` column in the table, then the trigger needs to be before update something as

```
delimiter //
create trigger `radia`.`orderstable_AFTER_UPDATE` 
before update on `orderstable`
for each row
begin
  set new.VATCharged = new.Amount * (new.VAT*0.01);
end ; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I changed it to exactly that. It still does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Please add the complete code i.e. how you are using `VATCharged` later in the trigger.

Comment: I have a similar trigger for before insert: 
'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `radia`.`orderstable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `orderstable` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET NEW.VATCharged = NEW.Amount * (NEW.VAT*0.01);
END'

Comment: where you are using `VATCharged` after the trigger ? Update the question and add the table structure too.

Comment: Updated the question. VATCharged gets put into a report using iReport.

Comment: Using the trigger before update has solved the problem. Thank you!